# What more can be done to add quality to Swing JPanel drawings?

Tags: java, performance, swing

I'm sorry if I have not worded the question title to well, so let me explain.

I am creating a game, actually a few and I see that most of the time when painting ect I use a JPanel, so I went and found a good method of painting (i.e it has great performance when multiple sprites etc are being painted) see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963494/java-2d-game-graphics. I implemented that into my own kind of *GameJPanel* which will allow me to always have performance when painting on my games `JPanel`s. Now to that I have added the methods like `setDoubleBuffered(true)` and [RenderHints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) on when drawing:

```
                if (isTextRenderHintsOn()) {
                    bg.setRenderingHints(textRenderHints);
                }
                if (isImageRenderHintsOn()) {
                    bg.setRenderingHints(imageRenderHints);
                }
                if (isColorRenderHintsOn()) {
                    bg.setRenderingHints(colorRenderHints);
                }
                if (isInterpolationRenderHintsOn()) {
                    bg.setRenderingHints(iterpolationRenderHints);
                }
                if (isRenderHintsOn()) {
                    bg.setRenderingHints(renderHints);
                }
```

now without going to other libraries etc what more can I do to adjust the quality and or performance of whats being drawn on the `JPanel`s?

It might also help to know that I use the `GraphicsEnviroment` and set the `JFrame` with the `JPanel` to full screen to gain a *hardware accelerated image via a Buffer Strategy* (not the linked performance drawing in swing also used some great techniques as is) below is an example of my `GameDrawLibrary` which implements the *Java2D game graphics links'* method and the rendering hints, the `FullScreen` class will be used for setting to and from full screen mode and the Test driver is just that:) :

Test Driver:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Test Driver
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class PureSwingPaintingTest extends JFrame {

    static GameDrawLibrary gdl;
    static Image image;
    static final FullScreen fs = new FullScreen();
    static int width = fs.getWidth(), height = fs.getHeight();

    public PureSwingPaintingTest() {
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gdl.createPanel();//create the panel
        JPanel panel = gdl.getPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("c:/chess.jpg")).getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        gdl = new GameDrawLibrary(width, height, true, true, true, true, true, true) {

            @Override
            void updateGame() {
                //update logic here
            }

            @Override
            void renderGame(Graphics2D g) {
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (fs.isSupported()) {
                    fs.setFullScreen(new PureSwingPaintingTest());
                } else {
                    fs.emulateFullScreen(new PureSwingPaintingTest());
                }

                gdl.showPanel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Game JPanel library of sorts:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

abstract class GameDrawLibrary extends JPanel {

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int scale;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private BufferStrategy strategy;
    private BufferedImage background;
    private Graphics2D backgroundGraphics;
    private Graphics2D graphics;
    private GraphicsConfiguration config = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    //graphics quaultiy settings
    private boolean textRenderHintsOn;
    private boolean imageRenderHintsOn;
    private boolean colorRenderHintsOn;
    private boolean interpolationRenderHintsOn;
    private boolean renderHintsOn;
    private RenderingHints textRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    private RenderingHints imageRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    private RenderingHints colorRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    private RenderingHints iterpolationRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    private RenderingHints renderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    public GameDrawLibrary() {
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        this.textRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.imageRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.colorRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.interpolationRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.renderHintsOn = false;
    }

    GameDrawLibrary(int width, int height) {
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scale = 1;
        this.textRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.imageRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.colorRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.interpolationRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.renderHintsOn = false;

    }

    GameDrawLibrary(int width, int height, int scale) {
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.textRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.imageRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.colorRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.interpolationRenderHintsOn = false;
        this.renderHintsOn = false;
    }

    public GameDrawLibrary(int width, int height, boolean textRenderHintsOn, boolean imageRenderHintsOn, boolean colorRenderHintsOn, boolean interpolationRenderHintsOn, boolean renderHintsOn, boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
        super(isDoubleBuffered);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scale = 1;
        this.textRenderHintsOn = textRenderHintsOn;
        this.imageRenderHintsOn = imageRenderHintsOn;
        this.colorRenderHintsOn = colorRenderHintsOn;
        this.interpolationRenderHintsOn = interpolationRenderHintsOn;
        this.renderHintsOn = renderHintsOn;
    }

    public GameDrawLibrary(int width, int height, int scale, boolean textRenderHintsOn, boolean imageRenderHintsOn, boolean colorRenderHintsOn, boolean interpolationRenderHintsOn, boolean renderHintsOn, boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
        super(isDoubleBuffered);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.textRenderHintsOn = textRenderHintsOn;
        this.imageRenderHintsOn = imageRenderHintsOn;
        this.colorRenderHintsOn = colorRenderHintsOn;
        this.interpolationRenderHintsOn = interpolationRenderHintsOn;
        this.renderHintsOn = renderHintsOn;
    }
    // Screen and buffer stuff

    private Graphics2D getBuffer() {
        if (graphics == null) {
            try {
                graphics = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return graphics;
    }

    private boolean updateScreen() {
        graphics.dispose();
        graphics = null;
        try {
            strategy.show();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            return (!strategy.contentsLost());

        } catch (NullPointerException | IllegalStateException e) {
            return true;

        }
    }

    // update game logic here
    abstract void updateGame();

    //paint stuff here
    abstract void renderGame(Graphics2D g);

    //create and return the already sized JFrame
    public void createPanel() {
        setSize(getRealWidth(), getRealHeight());
    }

    public void showPanel() {
        // Canvas
        canvas = new Canvas(config);
        canvas.setSize(width * scale, height * scale);
        add(canvas, 0);
        // Background & Buffer
        background = create(width, height, false);
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
        do {
            strategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        } while (strategy == null);

        startThread();//start thread to draw to the canvas
    }

    private void startThread() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                backgroundGraphics = (Graphics2D) background.getGraphics();
                long fpsWait = (long) (1.0 / 30 * 1000);

                main:
                while (isRunning) {
                    long renderStart = System.nanoTime();
                    updateGame();

                    // Update Graphics
                    do {
                        Graphics2D bg = getBuffer();

                        if (isTextRenderHintsOn()) {
                            bg.setRenderingHints(textRenderHints);
                        }
                        if (isImageRenderHintsOn()) {
                            bg.setRenderingHints(imageRenderHints);
                        }
                        if (isColorRenderHintsOn()) {
                            bg.setRenderingHints(colorRenderHints);
                        }
                        if (isInterpolationRenderHintsOn()) {
                            bg.setRenderingHints(iterpolationRenderHints);
                        }
                        if (isRenderHintsOn()) {
                            bg.setRenderingHints(renderHints);
                        }

                        if (!isRunning) {
                            break main;
                        }
                        renderGame(backgroundGraphics); // this calls your draw method
                        // thingy
                        if (scale != 1) {
                            bg.drawImage(background, 0, 0, width * scale, height * scale, 0, 0, width, height, null);
                        } else {
                            bg.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
                        }
                        bg.dispose();
                    } while (!updateScreen());

                    // Better do some FPS limiting here
                    long renderTime = (System.nanoTime() - renderStart) / 1000000;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, fpsWait - renderTime));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.interrupted();
                        break;
                    }
                    // renderTime = (System.nanoTime() - renderStart) / 1000000;

                }

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return this;
    }

    // create a hardware accelerated image
    public final BufferedImage create(final int width, final int height, final boolean alpha) {
        return config.createCompatibleImage(width, height, alpha ? Transparency.TRANSLUCENT : Transparency.OPAQUE);
    }

    public void setColorRenderHintsOn(boolean colorRenderHintsOn) {
        this.colorRenderHintsOn = colorRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public void setRenderHintsOn(boolean renderHintsOn) {
        this.renderHintsOn = renderHintsOn;
    }

    public void setInterpolationRenderHintsOn(boolean interpolationRenderHintsOn) {
        this.interpolationRenderHintsOn = interpolationRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public void setImageRenderHintsOn(boolean imageRenderHintsOn) {
        this.imageRenderHintsOn = imageRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public void setTextRenderHintsOn(boolean textRenderHintsOn) {
        this.textRenderHintsOn = textRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public boolean isColorRenderHintsOn() {
        return colorRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public boolean isInterpolationRenderHintsOn() {
        return interpolationRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public boolean isTextRenderHintsOn() {
        return textRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public boolean isImageRenderHintsOn() {
        return imageRenderHintsOn;
    }

    public boolean isRenderHintsOn() {
        return renderHintsOn;
    }

    public int getRealHeight() {
        return height * scale;

    }

    public int getRealWidth() {
        return width * scale;
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getScale() {
        return scale;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setScale(int scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }
}
```

Fullscreen class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class FullScreen {

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    Dimension screenSize;

    public FullScreen() {
        screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    }

    public void setFullScreen(JFrame frame) {
        if (gs.getFullScreenWindow() == null) {

            frame.dispose();
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            gs.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } else {// back to windowed mode
            emulateFullScreen(frame);
        }
    }

    public void emulateFullScreen(JFrame frame) {
        frame.dispose();
        frame.setUndecorated(false);
        gs.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return gs.getDisplayMode().getWidth();

    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return gs.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return gs.isFullScreenSupported();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but this seems more of a code-review type question than a specific single answer stackoverflow type question.

Comment: can you put a picture?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not really? I want to know what other ways the painting quality can be improved? maybe I'm missing something that can make quality better so I put specific code so that others may see what I have already impelemented for quality drawing?

Comment: a picture could be more readable than lots of code

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık I havent really got anything to compare it to as I havent implemented the drawing etc fully (I just use a simple `Image` for now) but I'd like to know besides the techniques already used how else can quality be improved

Comment: if doublebuffer clears the dirty line traces of fast-changing shapes, then quality is up to your imagination .

Comment: @David: you're asking in effect, "please review this code and see how it can be improved." Sorry, but this is a code review question, whether you agree or not.

Comment: @mKorbel well seen as you both say it is I have flagged it to be moved sorry for any inconvenience caused

Comment: @mKorbel I knew there had to be a downside! :(.. I havent heard of the Code Review site myself til today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a rather interesting piece of code, I'm going to enjoy reading it further when I have more time ;)

About the only things that jump out at me is how you are scaling your graphics.  I'd suggest having a read through http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html as it discuss `getScaledInstance` and some alternative algorithms.

That aside, I was told, some years ago, you can fake anti aliasing by scaling a image down by 4.  That is, if you want an output of a image at 800*600, you need to start with an image 4 times that size and scaling it down, which will produce a "fake" anti aliasing that does not rely on the hardware to render.

This may no longer hold true, but it might be of some worth to you

Comment: +1 Thank you...ah i always forget about the scaling downfalls. And thank you for the tips i might give it a try.